# Javascript/JQuery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen javascript code that uses variables as follows:

```
var defaultVar = { type : 'reports', order : 'ASC', column : '1' }
```

What kind of variables are these? When should it be used? Also, how do you access each element?

Comment: It's an object literal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11922384/1385672

Comment: [A re-introduction to JavaScript (JS Tutorial)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript). Note that "jQuery variable" isn't a thing - jQuery is essentially a collection of JavaScript functions, it doesn't have its own variables or syntax separate to what JavaScript has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals). Used like this it acts much like a dict, hash or associative array in other languages.

You should use it wherever you need to combine several variables or functions into a single entity.

You access the members like this:

```
defaultVar['type'] // -> 'reports'
defaultVar.type // -> 'reports'
defaultVar['order'] = "DESC"
defaultVar.order = "DESC"
```

Comment: The quotes are important: `defaultVar['type']`

Answer (score 1):

This is object in javascript. Currently its having type, order, column as its properties.

There are verious ways of creating object

```
Method 1: var obj = {name: 'robin', rollnumber : '1'}; 

Method 2 : var obj = new Object();  obj.name = 'robin'; obj.rollnumber = '1';
```

etc.

Objects can have methods as well. e.g. `var obj = {callMe : function () {//dosomthing}};`

To access elements of objects, just use dot (.) operator.

Comment: `also called as json`, that is incorrect.  JSON is a *string representation* of data that is a "subset of the object literal notation of JavaScript".  If it's not a string, it's *not* JSON.

Comment: You can also do `var obj = {};` instead of `var obj = new Object();` :-)

Comment: :) yes various ways. Javascript objects are just containers to hold key-value pairs

Answer (score -4):

Those are [JSON Objects](http://www.json.org/js.html) that can be accessed like so:

```
var type = defaultVar.type;
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON object".  He as an object literal.  JSON is a *string representation* of data; if it's not a string, it's not JSON.  The link says "JSON is a subset of the object literal notation of JavaScript".

Comment: I have been served. That's what I get for trying to pick the low hanging fruit :P Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score -5):

This is json syntax:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

this is used to create an associative array.

Comment: This is by no means to create an _associative array_, and it definitely isn't JSON

Comment: Not quite.  JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays.  Also, JSON is only when it's in a *string context*.  If it's not a string, it's not JSON.